# Hamilton's equations in classical physics

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

Basic question about one of Hamilton's equations:

$$
\dot{p}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}. \tag{1}
$$

I'm struggling to understand how this could be used to describe a system in which there is only a change in the kinetic energy - for example, a force applied to an object on a flat surface in which kinetic energy increases then decreases but with no change in the potential energy (as far as I can see). Since only the potential energy is a function of $q$ I don't see how the above can be applied.

The momentum, $p$, does depend on $q$, but if I allow $H$ to increase as the kinetic energy increases then the above appears to say that the force $\dot{p}$ is negative when the object ought to be accelerating and vice versa when it ought to be decelerating, which doesn't make sense of course.

I'm obviously misunderstanding something very fundamental, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Comment to the post (v3): Hamilton's equation (1) is essentially just Newton's 2nd law $\dot{p}=-\frac{\partial V}{\partial q}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hamiltonians describe systems--and that system must include what ever applies the force to the object on a flat surface. So if it's a hand, or a spring, an electric field, or a passing neutron star--you need to included that in the Hamiltonian--which, as you described, would be both $q$ and time dependent.

For the K.E. only Hamiltonian, there is no $\dot{p}$: objects at rest stay at rest, and objects in motion......